# How do I join a system to a domain using Win Vista Home Premium edition

Tags: windows

How do I join a system to a domain using Win Vista Home Premium edition?

Comment: The reason it's called "Home" is because it was never intended or designed to be used in a business environment, let alone joined to a domain.

Answer (score 17):

You can't.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929543

Comment: Even with the Windows Vista Home Premium Advanced Ultimate Ultra Plus with Extras Edition ? ;-)

Comment: @Kyle, only the one that comes in the pink and yellow box and has 6 groups of 5 characters in the serial number.